# XAMARIN: How to FindViewById<TabWidget> ??? (Resource not Found)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-resources

I'm getting a resource not found error when I try to do this:

```
    TabWidget tabz = FindViewById<TabWidget>(Resource.Id.tabs);
```

compiler doesn't see the TabWidget even when it's clearly labeled by id in my Main.axml file

Error CS0117 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'tabs'

Here's my full code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT, sorry, this is the full code... I don't know why I didn't copy this last time.  The above example is missing TabHost

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I force the compiler to recognize my tabs id? I've tried rebuilding the resource.designer.cs .. putting the declaration of TabWidget inside all of the activities... nothing works. My C# can't see the TabWidget

full project can be found here:

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_a2

I also tried this and it didn't work
[Xamarin Android Resource file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955548/xamarin-android-resource-file-not-found)

thanks, in advance

Comment: the problem is with the ResourceDesigner.cs file just comment this `TabWidget tabz = FindViewById<TabWidget>(Resource.Id.tabs);` and Rebuild your solution and it should start working properly if not revert

Comment: @G.hakim lol if I comment that out, then my TabWidget won't be accessible...

Comment: @hexagodI don't think you understood what I was saying just check my answer out below

Answer (score 0):

About the questions in your comment:

1,

> that is very good advice, but one note is that when
>   SetContentView(localLayout); is used inside an activity that already
>   has a content view, it crashes the app.

The app crashed because localLayout in SetContentView(localLayout) is a LinearLayout but a TabWidget needs a TabHost. So you can directly use:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

where Main.xaml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

2,

> LinearLayout localLayout =
>   FindViewById(Resource.Layout.Main); View
>   whichYouWantToUse_findViewById =
>   LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null); TextView tv =
>   FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView169); TabHost _tabHost =
>   (TabHost)whichYouWantToUse_findViewById.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabhost);
>   ' still can't see the tabhost ... I'm losing my mind here

The reason why you cannot see the tabhost is, firt, TabHost is FrameLayout, not LinearLayout, second, Resource.Id.tabhost should be Android.Resource.Id.TabHost. So I edited your code to :

```
    FrameLayout localLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Layout.Main);
    whichYouWantToUse_findViewById = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null);
    //TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
    TabHost _tabHost = (TabHost)whichYouWantToUse_findViewById.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
```

3,

> So the interesting thing is if I change tabhost to tahost ala
>   android:id="@+id/tahost" the resource appears in the designer but when
>   I change to android:id="@+id/tabhost" the resource disappears.. very
>   strange..

The id of TabHost need always be @android:id/tabhost", it cannot be modified to tahost or any others.

So the code in the onCreat Method is like this:

```
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    View whichYouWantToUse_findViewById = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);
    TextView textInAnotherLayout = (TextView)whichYouWantToUse_findViewById.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
    textInAnotherLayout.Text = "Yeah";

    TabHost tabHost = FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
    TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.TabWidget;
    var tabContent = tabHost.TabContentView;

    FrameLayout localLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Layout.Main);
    whichYouWantToUse_findViewById = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null);
    TabHost _tabHost = (TabHost)whichYouWantToUse_findViewById.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
```

### The following is the old answer.

---

> Answer modified: The way to get TabHost and TabWidget in Activity:
>
> ```
> TabHost tabHost = this.TabHost;
> TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.TabWidget;
> ```
>
> The way to use one resource from one XAML file in the activity for
>   another:
>
> ```
>     LinearLayout localLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Layout.Main);
>     SetContentView(localLayout);
>     View whichYouWantToUse_findViewById = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);
>     Button button1 = (Button)whichYouWantToUse_findViewById.FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);
> ```
>
> > I download your project and fixed this problem by modifying the property of >android:id

Comment: that's wassup!!  I'll test it out this evening when I get home.  thanks playboy

Comment: how do i make this work with TabHost ?  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl$PostInflateException: TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs"

Comment: After doing the research for your problem, I found that TabWidget is a special Layout in android, you cannot change the id and you have to get the widget by (tabHost.TabWidget) in your C# code. Now I will modify my answer and sorry for the wrong answer before.

Comment: no worries... thank you man.  We're all learning here.  Appreciate the help my dude

Comment: . now I'm just trying to figure out how use one resource from one XAML file in the activity for another.  I think I need to use a view inflation ?  Not expecting you to do my work tho... I'll post the answer once I know

Comment: I have modified the answer and also written an example code to use one resource from one XAML file in the activity for another.

Comment: my code still can't see the "tabs" resource or the "tabhost" inside an activity... Resource.Id does not contain a definition for tabs

Resource.Id does not contain a definition for tabhost
when I put inside the Activity but I do have resource definitions when I use this inside the MainActivity ... so I can go MainActivity >> Activity resource but not Activity >> MainActivity tabhost or tabs ... strange,  Still working on it.

Comment: that is very good advice, but one note is that when SetContentView(localLayout); is used inside an activity that already has a content view, it crashes the app.

Comment: '          LinearLayout localLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Layout.Main);

            View whichYouWantToUse_findViewById = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null);

            TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView169);

            TabHost _tabHost = (TabHost)whichYouWantToUse_findViewById.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabhost);   ' still can't see the tabhost ... I'm losing my mind here

Comment: So the interesting thing is if I change tabhost to tahost ala

android:id="@+id/tahost"

the resource appears in the designer but when I change to 

android:id="@+id/tabhost" 

the resource disappears.. very strange.. I'm going to try manually adding it into resource.designer.cs

Comment: I set the property using simply:
     TabHost tabHost;

            tabHost.TabWidget.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;

inside OnClick click listener 

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_a2/blob/2.762/Activities/ClickListeners.cs


and it worked... but still no object reference for tabhost when using the clever method you provided me inside my Activity classes


perhaps this is because the tabhost properties are only accessible within the tabhost itself?  I'm still working on this... very much appreciate the advice you've given me on inflating views.

Comment: I modified my answer yesterday according to your questions in your commen, but fogot to add this comment. Please refer to the modified answer and I think it would solve your problems and confusions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the visual studio compiler but the way that you have declared the id for your View,

If you check [this](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-layout-and-id-attribute/) blog by James White you will see how `Id` and the `Layout` Attributes actually work in Android,

The Right way of declaring the Id would be something like this `android:id="@+id/tabs"` whereas what you are doing is this `android:id="@android:id/tabs"`

Hence, When you do add them and try to find it using `Resource.Id.tabs`, There is nothing available in Id by the name tabs as it was never added by the Xamarin ResourceDesginer.cs file.

So the end result should actually be something like this :

```
  <TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffc916"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>
```

Also, note that I have replaced all the `fill_parent`'s with `match_parent`'s the reason behind it being that fill parent is now obsolete or you can say replaced (After API-8) and hence must not be used, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5761970/7462031).

**Update:**

I have updated the way tab host works, Also updated the XML above and I am adding a [reference link](https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/simple-android-tabhost-and-tabwidget-example.html) where you can find the right way of using both the TabHost and TabWidget, Also a good [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628047/xamarin-style-tabwidget) example for the same.

Comment: mono.android.DesignerException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl$PostInflateException
 at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:54)
 at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:235)
 at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:314)
 at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl$PostInflateException: TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".

Comment: .. for some reason when I copied my code it was missing the TabHost.  I've updated it to reflect my TabHost ... and I'm getting the above exception

Comment: thanks for the help guys... the real problem is that I'm unable to use resources from different XAML files without using what I'm pretty sure is supposed to be a view inflator.  I'm trying to work out the details now.  I'll post the full answer once I figure it out.

Comment: FYI, tabhost has to look like this or the app crashes
     <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

^^^ paste that into my code block

Comment: I had already done that do take a look and also i have updated the code

Comment: No the tabhost literally has to be named tabhost and not tabHost or this exception will occur Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Comment: Okay whatever i wouldn't be using this anyway, its just gotten old now you use viewpagers anyway. And okay updating it to tabhost

Comment: yeah lol .. I don't blame you.  Thanks for trying.  I don't even think this is possible to do.  I'm so far into the project though and the tabhost works fine... performance is better than the viewpager.  Someone else made a version of my app with the viewpager and the performance isn't as good as the actionbar.tabhost ... I appreciate the help anyway G.hakim

Comment: Okay anyway i will look into this thing later maybe anyway thanks for your time as well got to learn something new for a change \

Comment: uhh no... thank you sir.  You're the one helping me with my issue. =]  .. I'm still working on this.  It's a tricky little bugger.  I think we can only reference the tabhost from inside the tabhost.  Any attempt to set a parameter of the tabhost from in an activity is failing.  I did get the reference to work when the action modifies a property of tabhost ... so for example onclick of  tab hides the tabhost